# Calling a function second time causes null pointer dereference warning even if checked before

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, nullptr

Suppose we have the following piece of C++ code

```
const Person *Person::getParent() const {
    return m_condition ? m_parent : nullptr;
}

int Person::parentAge() const {
    // checking for nullptr
    if (getParent() == nullptr) {
        return -1;
    }

    return getParent()->getAge();  // warning: potential null pointer dereference
}
```

This is an overly simplified version, but I think it drives the point home. The point is, even though in the beginning of `parentAge()` method I have a guard condition to check whether or not `getParent()` returns `nullptr`, when compiling this code with `-Wnull-dereference` flag, I get the warning if I call the `getParent()` method even after the check. Why does this happen? Is it because of the way `getParent()` is written and the compiler doesn't "see" the guard condition, and will throw a warning if it sees that the method can potentially return a `nullptr`?

**For reference**, the warning is gone if I save the return value of `getParent()` into a variable and use it at a later point in time instead of calling the method again:

```
int Person::parentAge() const {
    // checking for nullptr
    auto parent = getParent();
    if (parent == nullptr) {
        return -1;
    }

    return parent->getAge();  // no warning generated here
}
```

Comment: The compiler probably determined that `m_condition` potentially can change between call 1 and call 2.

Comment: The risk of `m_condition` changing between the two calls increases if you tinker with it from different threads.

Comment: I see, that makes sense now. So I suppose calling the method only once and saving its result into a variable would indeed be a reasonable solution here.

Comment: If there is a race condition, saving the result could result in a dangling pointer being dereferenced.  And that'd be bad, too.